# How to catch the Control-C exception in a Visual C++ console app?

Tags: exception

This seems like it ought to be simple, but I've tried both
`try {} catch (...) {}`   C++ exception handling and
`__try {} __finally {}`   structured exception handling (SEH)
and neither one will catch the exception that happens when you Control-C the application.

I didn't really expect C++ exception handling to do this, since the Control-C is a system-type signal and not caused by a C++ throw(), but I tried it anyway when SEH didn't work.

If I run under a debugger, it shows that Control-C raises a first-chance exception, but when it's rethrown, my handler is never invoked.

Comment: It's not an exception, its called an interupt.

Comment: @Daniel  Yeah, technically Microsoft should call it Structured INTERRUPT Handling, but they don't.  Po-tAY-to Po-tAH-to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how to handle an interrupt in Win32.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  I had spent at least an hour searching MSDN with different search engines without finding this.