# Proper use of cudaDeviceReset()

Tags: cuda

Since I'm having suspicions the "black box" (GPU) is not shutting down cleanly in some larger code ([others perhaps too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294595/handling-ctrlc-exception-with-gpu)), I would include a `cudaDeviceReset()` at the end of `main()`. But wait! This would `Segmentation fault` all instances of classes statically created in `main()` with non-trivial CUDA code in destructors, right? E.g.

```
class A {
public:
  cudaEvent_t tt;
  cudaEvent_t uu;
  A() { 
    cudaEventCreate(&tt);
    cudaEventCreate(&uu);
  }
  ~A(){  
    cudaEventDestroy(tt);
    cudaEventDestroy(uu);
  }
};
```

instantiated statically:

```
int main() {
  A t;
  cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
}
```

segfaults on exit. Question: is perhaps `cudaDeviceReset()` invoked automatically on exit from `main()`?

Otherwise whole useful code of `main()` should be shifted to some `run()`, and `cudaDeviceReset()` should be the as last command in `main()`, right?

Comment: cudaDeviceReset explicitly destroys any context on the active device being held by process or thread that calls it. But that it all it does. If you have CUDA API calls which need a context to work in destructor code, then you can't have them called after the context is already destroyed (and it will be destroyed automatically by the runtime when the process terminates).

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Talonmies, the destructor of class A is called after the cudaDeviceReset() function is already called, namely when the main(..) function finishes.

I think, you may take cudaDeviceReset() to an atexit(..) function.

```
void myexit() {
  cudaDeviceReset();
}

int main(...) {
  atexit(myexit); 
  A t;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you may try to take the declaration of "t" in another parenthesis. And then call cudaDeviceReset after the end of this paranthesis. So it may force the destruction of the "t" before the device reset.. """int main(..) {  { A t; t.someoperation(); } cudaDeviceReset(); }"""

Comment: Thanks. I think it is a good point. I will check as soon as I can and let you know.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion by Talonmies at [CUDA streams destruction and CudaDeviceReset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979982/cuda-streams-destruction-and-cudadevicereset/16982503?noredirect=1#comment24536013_16982503) on this topic.

Comment: Yes, Talonmies is the king especially if the topic is CUDA. I really curious which CUDA related questions he has answered. Lets see. Thanks Talonmies.