# Generating random number in cuda kernel between 0 and 1

Tags: random, cuda, gpgpu

I have a cuda application where I want to generate random numbers between 0 and 1. I have written a dummy code where a matrix of size 8x256 would be filled up by random numbers generated by kernel. My original matrix would be something like 8XBIG_NUMBER. But probably I am missing something in my code because of which I am not able to produce the desired result.I am posting my code below.

```
void main(int argc,char* argv[])    
{
    float *test_var,*dev_test;
    curandState *state;

    test_var = (float *)malloc(8*256*sizeof(float));
    memset(test_var,0,8*256*sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_test,8*256*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_test,test_var,8*256*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 gridDim(1,256/32,1);
    dim3 blockDim(8,32,1);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&state,8*256*sizeof(curandState));
    setup_kernel<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(state,unsigned(time(NULL)));
    test_kernel<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(state,dev_test);
    cudaMemcpy(test_var,dev_test,8*256*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    system("PAUSE");

    for (int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {   for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
        { printf("%f\t",test_var[i*8+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_test);
    cudaFree(state);
    free(test_var);
    exit(0);
}

__global__ void setup_kernel(curandState *state,unsigned long seed)
{
    int id_col  = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    int id_row = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

    curand_init(seed,(id_row*8+id_col),0,&state[id_row*8+id_col]);
}

__global__ void test_kernel(curandState *state,float *dev_test)
{
    int id_col  = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    int id_row = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

     curandState local_state = state[id_row*8+id_col];
     dev_test[id_row*8+id_col] = curand(&local_state);   
     state[id_row*8+id_col] = local_state;
}
```

I want to generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each of those cells in the matrix. I would really appreciate of anyone's assistance. Thank you

Comment: Is there something wrong with `curandGenerateUniform()`?

Comment: I haven't tried that. But I was trying to generate a random number which does not belong to any distribution. That is why I was curand().

Comment: A random number belonging to "no distribution" doesn't make sense. That's like saying a line with "no shape". A uniform distribution is just what it sounds like: each value between 0 and 1 is equally likely.

Comment: Yeah I can understand what you are trying to say. Actually I was trying to generate the numbers using multinomial distribution. But since it is not present in the library I was trying to use curand().

Comment: I'm not into cuda rand, but, it's doesn't make scene to init the seed multiple times, the setup_kernel seems weird to me, it's seems like it has to be done only once, that's only an assumption

Comment: Probably it would be beneficial if you would post an actually compilable version of the code with all the extra lines comprising the function prototypes, includes and whatever, so that one could easily compile your code and help you, see Talonmies' [rant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979982/cuda-streams-destruction-and-cudadevicereset) to one of my posts :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the curand [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html#topic_1_3), you'll note the declaration given for the device api function you are using:

```
__device__ unsigned int curand (curandState_t *state)
```

This particular API call returns an `unsigned int`.  So you're not going to get floating point values unless you modify it somehow.

Since it returns `unsigned int` values, one possible modification would simply be to scale the result:

```
 dev_test[id_row*8+id_col] = curand(&local_state)/(float)(0x0FFFFFFFFUL);
```

This modification should give you floating point values between 0 and 1.  However this is rather crude for a variety of reasons.  As suggested in the comments, it makes more sense to select one of the device generators that will do this for you, such as:

```
 dev_test[id_row*8+id_col] = curand_uniform(&local_state);
```

I'm not an expert on this, but it seems that a multinomial distribution is fundamentally a discrete distribution.  Therefore, you will need some method to convert a continuous-valued distribution to a discrete one, if you intend to start with floating point random numbers between 0 and 1.  Wikipedia gives [a method for doing this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) starting with continuous-valued random numbers between 0 and 1, and based on my read of that method, the `curand_uniform` distribution/generator would be a reasonable starting point.