# cudaDeviceReset causes memory leak?

Tags: cuda

I tried the following code with cuda 7.0.

If I set `n_repeat` to 1 and remove the last `cudaDeviceReset`, the code runs fine.

If I set `n_repeat` to 1 and keep the `cudaDeviceReset`, I can run the code segment towards the end but I got a memory leak detected by my memory leak detector after running the program.

If I set `n_repeat` to 2 and keep the `cudaDeviceReset`, I got an error in the second time I reach `cublasCreate`. The error code is `CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED`.

Can some one let me know what is the problem here and is `cudaDeviceReset` for the purpose of cleaning up between different runs of using the GPU, like what I'm trying to do here?

```
int device_id_ = 0;
cublasHandle_t blas_;
curandGenerator_t rand_gen_;
long alloc_size = 1000;
char* raw_;
int n_repeat = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < n_repeat; ++i) {
  CHECK_CUDA(cudaSetDevice(device_id_));
  CHECK_CUDA(cublasCreate(&blas_));
  CHECK_CUDA(curandCreateGenerator(&rand_gen_, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));
  CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&raw_, alloc_size));
  CHECK_CUDA(curandDestroyGenerator(rand_gen_));
  CHECK_CUDA(cublasDestroy(blas_));
  CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(raw_));

  CHECK_CUDA(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be the case here. If you create an object (a buffer for example) for which the destructor is called upon getting out-of-scope to free-up the resources, calling `cudaDeviceReset()` inside the same scope can cause problem. See the comment on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11608350/2386951).

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Presumably your question is actually about `cublasCreate` causing a segfault if called twice? The memory leak is probably irrelevant in this case. There are lots of perfectly safe pieces of code that generate false positives in checkers like valgrind.

Comment: when I run your program on CUDA 7.0 or  CUDA 7.5RC on linux, every single API status return value is zero.  What CUDA version are you using? My example is [here](http://pastebin.com/WBp67RVx).

Comment: @talonmies: is cublasCreate calling twice allowed? Or will it cause a problem?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: did you try the `n_repeat = 2` case?

Comment: Did you even look at the example?  I posted the entire code I used plus the output.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry Robert, and thank you for the help. I must have messed up some other configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even with the example from Robert Crovella, cuda 7 ubuntu 14.04, K40c

Adding `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after `cudaSetDevice` and before `cublasCreate()` made it work for me